# CanUserAddRows New Row not saving in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Created `DataGrid` and set `CanUserAddRows="True"`

Have a button which saves updates in the cs file:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UnitService unitService = new UnitService();

    unitService.SaveUpdates(valuationCase);

    MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();
    mainWin.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

There is also a `textbox` not in the `datagrid` on the window which is editable and this is correctly saving edits with the save click button. Just the new rows aren't.

Any  ideas??

datagrid definition:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgCommentsList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,196,9.953,38.204" CanUserAddRows="True" FontSize="18">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="bold" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Type" Text="{Binding Type}" >
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="TextBox.IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="TextBox.IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: can you please post the datagrid definition.

Comment: added above. it includes a workaround for binding an IsReadOnly property but that part works

Answer (score 0):

You should commit the edit on the row using `dataGrid.CommitEdit()`

Edit: After diagnosing the issue here goes

You either need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your DataContext class (i.e: Viewmodel) like so:

```
 public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
            private string _type;
            public string Type 
            {
                get { return _type; } 
                set 
                {
                    _type = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Type");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
}
```

Or you extend from DependencyObject and use Dependency Properties, like so:

```
 public class ViewModel: DependencyObject
 {

            public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Type", typeof (string), typeof (ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

            public int Type
            {
                get { return (int) GetValue(TypeProperty ); }
                set { SetValue(TypeProperty , value); }
            }
 }
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I dont have any set rows so where in my code should I add this??

Comment: in the Save_Click handler make a call to dgCommentsList.CommitEdit(). It will commit your edit. This will trigger the EditEnding events on the row. You can handle those events to do want you wish with the edited row.

Comment: It didn't work. this is probably worth mentioning - i tried this on another branch with a lot of unversioned files and it worked, with no additional code. I lost that version and now it's just not working here.

Comment: Don't know if I understood correctly. What you're saying is that you tried the solution I provided on another branch and it worked and now it doesn't? Am I right? If so you should check to see what was introduced in the changes that might cause the operation to fail.

Comment: No, not your changes. My original code worked previously. The only changes from that were non versioned files - so i don't understand why it's not working now. However your solution is also not working

Comment: Have you checked the IsReadOnly value? Because if it's true you won't be able to update the TextBox's value. And also you should simply Bind the IsReadOnly property of the text box to the your property instead of having those DataTriggers. But that's just a matter of code simplicity, I don't think it's related to the issue you're having.

Comment: The IsReadOnly is a bool which is set somewhere else depending on if it's been pulled from the server. This was the only way I found to set it. I never considered that the read only property would transfer to the new row. It still allows me to actually input values but just doesn't save them.

Comment: Please provide more information in the question about how are you handling edit events on the DataGrid. and also, does you're DataContext implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Or is the Type property a Dependency Property?

Comment: Type is a property in my viewModel, as is IsReadOnly( but this is set to true/false in other places in my project) - so should change depending on what point the user opens the datagrid to view/edit it).I'm a bit confused on your question about INotifyPropertyChanged, I don't implement this. Basically, I think it's a problem with me binding the isreadonly property and each time a new row is created it sets the new row to IsReadOnly=true. the problem doesn't occur if I use an easy column definition ie. <DataGridTextColumn Header="Case Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />

Comment: Okay then that is the problem! :) If you don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged the property won't update because the UI thread cannot notify the DataContext of this change. You need to implement this or use a dependency property. I'll update the answer with the details ;)

Comment: Didn't work - also I have more than one row on my datagrid and this seems like a lot of work to do PER property. I've decided to change the way I'm approaching what I'm trying to do because this seems like an issue which isn't able to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and effort though :)

Comment: Well sorry that I couldn't be of more assistance ;) good luck with you project :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the mode of the binding for it to write back to the underlying object.Plus I noticed your DataGrid does not have an ItemsSource. I'm guessing as this was just a snippet that you left it out.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Type" Text="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but this isn't working either. Also, when i use an "easy" column definition like in the most recent comment to the above answer, all I have to do is hit Enter and a new row appears and saves the previous. Enter button does nothing when using my binded text boxes. Dunno if this helps

Comment: Update: I tried the Mode=TwoWay on the DataTrigger binding for IsReadOnly, and when I ran the code it returned an error which stated that :
"A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'IsReadOnly'"

Don't know if this is related.

Comment: Mode=TwoWay will only work on properties that can read and write ie: prop { get; set; }